# Octave: How can I index single element of an array?

Tags: matlab, octave

I have the following code written in Octave:

```sh
  1 %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------% 
  2 % INPUT SIGNAL %                                                                
  3 %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------% 
  4                                                                                 
  5 sampling_frequency = 8000;                                                      
  6 sampling_period = 1/sampling_frequency;                                         
  7 samples_count = 8;                                                              
  8 time_samples = sampling_period * (0 : samples_count-1);                         
  9                                                                                 
 10                                                                                 
 11 amplitude_1 = 1;                                                                
 12 frequency_1 = 1000;                                                             
 13 phase_shift_1 = 0;                                                              
 14 signal_samples_1 = amplitude_1*sin(2*pi * frequency_1 * ...             
 15     time_samples + phase_shift_1);                                              
 16                                                                                 
 17                                                                                 
 18 amplitude_2 = 0.5;                                                              
 19 frequency_2 = 2000;                                                             
 20 phase_shift_2 = 3*pi/4;                                                         
 21 signal_samples_2 = amplitude_2*sin(2*pi * frequency_2 * ...             
 22     time_samples + phase_shift_2);                                              
 23                                                                                 
 24 signal_samples = signal_samples_1 + signal_samples_2;             
 25 for samples_index = 0 : samples_count-1                                         
 26     fprintf(stdout, "Sample %d: ", samples_index)                               
 27 endfor                                                                          
 28
```

As you may see, at line `25`, I would like to print value of each sample at separate line, i.e.

```sh
Sample <sample_number>: <sample_value>
```

My question is: how can I index separate member of an array (e.g. `input_signal` array)?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution by myself, so I would like to share it with you.

```sh
signal_samples = signal_samples_1 + signal_samples_2;                           
for samples_index = 1 : samples_count                                           
    fprintf(stdout, "Sample %d: %8.5f\n", samples_index-1, ...                    
        signal_samples(samples_index:samples_index))                            
endfor
```

**Output**:

```sh
Sample 0:  0.35355
Sample 1:  0.35355
Sample 2:  0.64645
Sample 3:  1.06066
Sample 4:  0.35355
Sample 5: -1.06066
Sample 6: -1.35355
Sample 7: -0.35355
```

Comment: `signal_samples(samples_index)` will do.

Comment: Checked and confirmed!